# Pulling object out of named list using r

Tags: r, model, data-manipulation

I'm trying to pull the psi terms and their corresponding variables out in a `tibble` or `dataframe`.  When I try `glm.fitted.segmented$....`, I don't see `psi` as an option.  When I click the model object in the global environment of RStudio, then I do see the psi there under `xlevels: Named list()`.

Ideally, I'm looking to have a `dataframe` in the following format

```
 Variable         PSI
 Age              50
 Age              53
 off.set.term     4.369448
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to pull this object out? Thank you.

```
library(segmented)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
#create target variable
Y<-c(13,21,12,11,16,9,7,5,8,8) 
#create independent variables
X<-c(74,81,80,79,89,96,69,88,53,72)
age<-c(50.45194,54.89382,46.52569,44.84934,53.25541,60.16029,50.33870,
   51.44643,38.20279,59.76469)
#put together in data frame and develop initial model
dat=data.frame(Y=Y,off.set.term=log(X),age=age)
glm.fit=glm(Y~age+off.set.term,data=dat,family=poisson)

#fit segmented model
glm.fitted.segmented <- segmented(glm.fit, seg.Z=~age + off.set.term, psi = 
list(age = c(50,53), off.set.term = c(4.369448)))
summary(glm.fitted.segmented)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`psi` is an element of `glm.fitted.segmented`; you can look through everything in it by writing `str(glm.fitted.segmented)`.

See:

```
> glm.fitted.segmented$psi
                    Initial      Est.    St.Err
psi1.age          50.000000 51.847375 3.7901326
psi2.age          53.000000 57.873361 4.5794829
psi1.off.set.term  4.369448  4.313503 0.7814676
```

To make a table with the rownames (= variable names in this case), use:

```
glm.fitted.segmented$psi %>% as.data.frame() %>% rownames_to_column()
            rowname   Initial      Est.    St.Err
1          psi1.age 50.000000 51.847375 3.7901326
2          psi2.age 53.000000 57.873361 4.5794829
3 psi1.off.set.term  4.369448  4.313503 0.7814676
```

Comment: Thank you @Jesse Tweedle.  However when I do 
    psi2 <- as_tibble(piecewise_seg2$ psi 
it takes only the three columns. Not the actual variables, which I also need to do a join later.  How can I pull those out?

Comment: Nevermind @Jesse Tweedle.  
    Instead of doing `as_tibble`, I used `as.data.frame` and it worked! Thank you.

Comment: `as.data.frame` will keep the rownames, but the rownames won't be a variable, if that's what you need (esp. for a join). I'll update to add them.

Comment: I used `rownames_to_column` to coerce them as a column.  Now researching how to parse the "psi1." off.  I'm thinking `str_split`.  As you can probably tell, I'm a rookie hacking my way through this.